# Live Objects MQTT connection with node.js

Tags: mqtt, iot, orange-api

I would like to implement Live Objects MQTT interface for my app, but i’m not very familiar with this protocol. Anyone has examples of code to setup a connection correctly?

Thx for your replies!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, just asking for help without showing what you have already tried is not likely to get much response. Please read the following doc about asking good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit the question to include what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find some sample of code for node.js on Github https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/LiveObjects-samples-nodejs

It exists also for other platforms with links on Github here: https://developer.orange.com/apis/datavenue/code-sample

regards

Comment: /!\ old links. For sample code go here : https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/#/cms/ressources-exemples-de-codes/?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const mqttTopic = "router/~event/v1/data/new/urn/lora/#";
const url = "mqtt://liveobjects.orange-business.com:1883";
const apiKey ="<your api key>";

let client = mqtt.connect(url, {
  username: "payload",
  password: apiKey,
  keepAlive: 30
});

client.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("Connected to Live Objects");
  client.subscribe(mqttTopic);
  console.log("MQTT::Subscribed to topic:", mqttTopic);
});

client.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("MQTT::Error from client --> ", err);
});

client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
  let loraMessage = JSON.parse(message);
  <your code here>
});
```